# Downloading file using command line tool in Linux VM which requires sign-in

Tags: lynx, w3m, elinks

**Environment**: Linux VM which I have access only through command line console.

**Goal**:
I need to download the file: https://download.nlm.nih.gov/umls/kss/2020AA/umls-2020AA-full.zip
Unlike typical download using `wget`, this redirects to a sign-in page.

**What I have tried till now**:

Tried using the text based browsers: [w3m](https://www.howtogeek.com/103574/how-to-browse-from-the-linux-terminal-with-w3m/), [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/). Until recent changes in the sign-in page, it used to work.

**What had changed in the sign-in page?**

Earlier the sign-in page used to take username and password. But recently they have introduced option to sign-in via Google, Microsoft etc.

**Problem**

The sign-in page looks like this in my local m/c:

[image]

But when browsing using text based browsers in the VM, it only shows a blank page.

Is there any solution to this issue?

N.B.

- The link to above zip file is mentioned in https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/licensedcontent/umlsarchives04.html#2020AA
- As it is a huge file, I don't have the option to download in my local system and then upload it to the VM.
- Had originally asked the question in StackOverflow, but was suggested to raise the question in this forum (so I deleted the original post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UMLS files can be downloaded programmatically using the API tokens. The procedure is outlined here: https://documentation.uts.nlm.nih.gov/automating-downloads.html

- Step 1: Get your API key from your UMLS profile.
  You can find the API key in the UTS ‘My Profile’ area after signing in.
- Step 2: use the below script to download the required files:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

export apikey=$1
export DOWNLOAD_URL=$2

export CAS_LOGIN_URL=https://utslogin.nlm.nih.gov/cas/v1/api-key


if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then echo "Usage: download.sh apikey download_url"
                      echo "  e.g. download.sh e33c59db-1234-abcd-efgh-0117ab2cd5gh2  https://download.nlm.nih.gov/umls/kss/rxnorm/RxNorm_full_current.zip"
                      echo "       download.sh e33c59db-1234-abcd-efgh-0117ab2cd5gh2 https://download.nlm.nih.gov/umls/kss/rxnorm/RxNorm_weekly_current.zip"
   exit
fi


if [ -z "$apikey" ]; then echo " Please enter you api key "
   exit
fi

if [ -z "$DOWNLOAD_URL" ]; then echo " Please enter the download_url "
   exit
fi


TGT=$(curl -d "apikey="$apikey -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST https://utslogin.nlm.nih.gov/cas/v1/api-key)

TGTTICKET=$(echo $TGT | tr "=" "\n")

for TICKET in $TGTTICKET
do
    if [[ "$TICKET" == *"TGT"* ]]; then
      SUBSTRING=$(echo $TICKET| cut -d'/' -f 7)
      TGTVALUE=$(echo $SUBSTRING | sed 's/.$//')
    fi
done
echo $TGTVALUE
STTICKET=$(curl -d "service="$DOWNLOAD_URL -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST https://utslogin.nlm.nih.gov/cas/v1/tickets/$TGTVALUE)
echo $STTICKET

curl -c cookie.txt -b cookie.txt -L -O -J $DOWNLOAD_URL?ticket=$STTICKET
rm cookie.txt
```

Save the above script to a file named `download.sh` and can be invoked as below:

```bsh
$ bash download.sh e33c59db-1234-abcd-efgh-0117ab2cd5gh2  https://download.nlm.nih.gov/umls/kss/2020AB/umls-2020AB-full.zip
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated script.  
Would be nice if you can mention the correct URL link in the last line.  
You have mixed up 2020AA with 2020AB :)